# Los Diablos Rojos del México -- ¿por qué "del"?

Tags: deportes

Hay un equipo en la Liga Mexicana de Béisbol llamado Los Diablos Rojos **del** México.

En su nombre, ¿por qué no se emplea "de" sino "del"?

Answer (score 3):

Existe otro equipo que se llama **Rojos del Ejido**, nombre que se debe a que son el equipo de béisbol que pertenece al **Club Polideportivo Ejido**.

A partir de esta pobre evidencia, pero considerando además [este artículo](http://www.milb.com/news/article.jsp?ymd=20150330&content_id=115553142&fext=.jsp&vkey=news_l125&sid=l125) que habla del ingreso del **Club México** a la Liga Mexicana hace 75 años, podemos suponer que el origen del nombre está en que los **Diablos Rojos** son el equipo de beisbol **del Club México**. No serían del *país* México (que no lleva artículo "el") sino del *club* México (que sí lleva artículo). Y por sinécdoque o por el simple paso del tiempo se perdió la palabra **club**.

Mi respuesta es sólo una suposición. Soy chileno y no tengo ninguna referencia acerca de los clubes deportivos mexicanos y mucho menos del béisbol. Pero sirve como hipótesis.

Comment: No sé si es correcta o no pero tu respuesta sí sirve como hipótesis. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

En ciertos contextos literarios se usa un artículo precediendo a un nombre propio para realzar una posibilidad entre varias, en un momento determinado en el tiempo o relacionado con algún rasgo que sea distintivo. Por ejemplo:

- El Nilo más salvaje.
- La España que todos queremos.
- La Rusia zarista.
- El México colonial.

En algunos casos, un nombre propio incluye nombres comunes, como en Los Estados Unidos de América, donde "estados" sería un nombre común.

Además, en los países de latinoamérica se ha desarrollado el español de diversas formas, dándose el caso de que en algunos de esos países se estila el artículo como parte del nombre del país. Por ejemplo, en Argentina no es inusual que se refieran a su país como "La Argentina".

En el caso de ese equipo deportivo, el nombre original "Los rojos del México" empleaba esta forma de referencia a "El México", aunque no estoy seguro de que hoy en día sea algo común en ese país.

Comment: Aunque lo que dices es cierto, no es aplicable a este caso, porque *México* no lleva después ningún calificativo. Por otro lado, no tengo noticia de que nunca se haya usado el artículo con *México*, a diferencia de lo ocurrido con otros países latinoamericanos (además de *la Argentina*, se me ocurren *el Perú* o *el Brasil*), pero aquí puedo estar equivocado.

Answer (score -2):

> Liga **Mexicana** de Béisbol llamado Los Diablos Rojos del México

La liga es mexicana, pues ya sabemos que los juegos pasan en el país México.  Y en México existe una ciudad epónima.  El Distrito Federal de México / Distrito. Federal. (D.F)

Pero la mayoría de la gente mexicana se refieren a esa ciudad como `México`.  Tambien es común oír `D.F`.

> Ayer nos fuimos al D.F
>
> Mi madre nació en el México.
>
> Nuestro capital se ubica en el Distrito Federal de México.

Comment: ¿? This doesn't answer the question at all. Also two of the examples are wrong.